# Cutting out white (low contrast) objects from white background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background, white

[image]I need to figure out the most efficient way to make quick cutouts of white products and a white background. I usually make a copy of the blue channel, level it out and paint over the rest, but it's a pain when I have to cut 40 pics with predominant white cloth.

P.S. My eyes hurt, plz hlp

**UPDATE**

I am not the photographer and i cant request the photos be made on a green screen.

Comment: Not going to be easy to offer suggestions without seeing a sample or a few

Comment: What program are you using?

Comment: Are you the photographer? One trick is to have strobe the lights during a quick bracket so that you have one where the subject is lit, one where the background is lit, and one with both. The one where the subject is unlit can be used as a stencil/silhouette

Comment: I dont know why people are downvoting this. Its a good question and you showed effort. I gave it an upvote. How clean do you need it to be in the areas with hair?

Comment: I agree, good question.  I really don't think there is a fast way to do this kind of selection. You seem to have the right idea but if there is a better way, I'm ALL ears.

Comment: Thanks for the support in my suffering. The hair needs to be kind of clean, I use the cutouts on online and offline ads.

Answer (score 1):

1. Separate the background light from the subject light
2. Use a green background (green screen)
3. Make sure the green light reflected does not spill on the subject
4. In post production, select the green background

If you need to work with existing photographs with attributes you are describing, your options are what you are doing, combined with quick select tool and refine edge/refine mask.

ADDENDUM:

It appears that your choices may be limited in producing the original. In that case, and if you are not already using it, I will suggest a process that may make the selection go a little quicker. If you are already using it, ignore the suggestion.

1. When you select the blue channel and duplicate it, you will paint the white-ish areas as white and the subject as black
2. When you pick up the paint brush to paint the border areas, change the brush blend mode (not the layer blend mode) to Overlay
3. Now, when you pick up white and start painting on the background Photoshop will try to prevent the brush from painting on the dark areas
4. When you pick up black and paint on the subject, the same will prevent spills into the background
5. Then you can convert this alpha channel to a mask on the layer and refine it to taste, I will recommend against extracting the subject because you will leave pixels behind. With a layer mask you have more flexibility.

I did not gather from your brief explanation that you were doing this, I though I would add it here.

Comment: I can't do that request to the photographers because we use the photos with white background for the shop with different resolutions.

Comment: If you can easily extract the subject from the background, you can put it against any color background you like, including white. It is a strategic choice considering all possible uses of the photographs. Or, you stick with the method you currently use.